# OptaPlanner @PlanningPin, null entities and .fromUniquePair()

Tags: optaplanner

I need some clarification, maybe someone can help me about the pinned and null entities with `.from()`. I understand that I need to use `.fromUnfiltered()` to get them in the stream. But what about `.fromUniquePair()`, are entities propagated down the stream if they are null and pinned ? Similar question if I use `.fromUnfiltered()` with a `.join()`, will the `join()` take the null and pinned entities in the second class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinning has no effect on Constraint Streams - both from() and join() will always include pinned entities. Let's therefore concentrate on the uninitizalized entities.

The thing to understand about `fromUniquePair(Something.class)` is that it is a shorthand for the following:

```
from(Something.class)
   .join(Something.class, ...) // Replace "..." with joiners to get unique pairs.
```

Therefore, both the left and the right will retrieve only initialized entities. If you want unique pairs including uninitialized entities, you will have to give up the shorthand and use a nested stream:

```
fromUnfiltered(Something.class)
    .join(fromUnfiltered(Something.class), ...) // Replace "..." with the same joiners as above.
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for this very clear answer, it helps me a lot!